# Google BigQuery has a syntax error: Unexpected keyword between?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm doing a simple query

```
SELECT * 
FROM `bq-julius.stackoverflow.partitioned_questions` 
WHERE BETWEEN DATE(creation_date) = "2022-07-11" AND DATE(creation_date) = "2021-01-01"
```

Why am I getting "unexpected between keyword" error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as per https://blog.coupler.io/bigquery-between/#BigQuery_Between_Syntax, the syntax is like:

> SELECT column_name(s)
> FROM table_name
> WHERE column_name BETWEEN value1 AND value2

so you may want to try this, where <date_column> is your real column name for the datetime:

> Blockquote
> SELECT * FROM `bq-julius.stackoverflow.partitioned_questions` WHERE `<date_column>` BETWEEN '2022-07-11' AND '2021-01-01'

Comment: I've tried that and nothing returns because <date_column> is a utc timestamp format

Comment: @dev, try this **WHERE DATE(creation_date) BETWEEN "2021-01-01" AND "2022-07-11"**.  Earlier date should be put before.